# How does package location work in Dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm working through the example at http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/hello_dojo/demo/module.html and I've created a directory structure as follows

```
w:/djt2/index.html
w:/djt2/js/mymodule.js  (exact copy of http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/hello_dojo/demo/myModule.js)
```

I then set the Tinyweb web-server to serve localhost from w:/djt2

I've changed `index.html` a tiny bit, to adjust for putting `mymodule.js` inside the `js` subdirectory (I've removed comments too below):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tutorial: Hello Dojo!</title>

    <script>
        var dojoConfig = {
            async: true,
            packages: [{
                name: "djt2",
                location: '/js'     /* Location #1 */
            }]
        };
    </script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="greeting">Hello</h1>
<script>
    require(["djt2/mymodule"], function(myModule){   /* Location #2 */
        myModule.setText("greeting", "Hello Dojo!");
        setTimeout(function(){
            myModule.restoreText("greeting");
        }, 3000);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This works, but I'm not entirely sure I understand why... In particular, at Location #1, the original had `location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, '')` which evaluates to the empty string and makes the loader look for mymodule.js at the CDN location (I also tried to set location to `"/"`, but that made it search at `http://mymodule.js/`).

At Location #2 it is a little mystical that the prefix should be `djt2/`...

If someone could explain it, or direct me to the documentation (I'm a bit overwhelmed with learning a new framework :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an extra `djt2` directory in your structure

```
w:/djt2/js/djt2/mymodule.js
```

Set the baseUrl in the configuration.

```
var dojoConfig = {
    async: true,
    baseUrl: '/js'
    packages: [{
         name: "djt2",
         location: 'djt2'
    }]
};
```

Setting the baseUrl will tell dojo where to look for custom modules.  The location that is part of the package is relative to the baseUrl.

---

I always think of modules/packages as namesapces.  To extend your example with an additional package, it would look like the following:

```
w:/djt2/js/another/anotherModule.js

var dojoConfig = {
    async: true,
    baseUrl: '/js'
    packages: [{
         name: "djt2",
         location: 'djt2'
    }, {
         name: "another",
         location: 'another'
    }]
};
```

Comment: hmm.. that didn't work. It tried to fetch mymodule.js from `http://localhost/djt2/js/djt2/mymodule.js`, but since I'm serving from `w:/djt2` there is no `djt2` folder off of root.  If I change baseUrl to just `"/js"` it works.  If I change the baseUrl to `"/js/djt2"` and remove the packages definition it also works...

Comment: I missed the part where localhost mapped to djt2.  Yes, baseUrl should then be /js.  Dojo will look for module definitions that begin with djt2 in the djt2 directory off of /js

Comment: /me wonders what will happen when a dijit or dojox is required, one that resides in the google cdn

Comment: I have a sandbox app that uses CDN and has a custom module that is on the web server and it works fine.  dojo, dijit and dojox are loaded from cdn.  The custom module from the web server.